# Advertisements on a window in spritekit apps (swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, iad

I have an app with an iAd banner in the bottom of the view. I have played other apps that shows a window with an advertisement...

Anyone knows how to do that?  I'm working on swift and spritekit, and I have not found documentation about that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for **"Interstitial Ads"**.

And you can find relevant information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Full-ScreenAdvertisements/Full-ScreenAdvertisements.html)